# How do I use a SQL CLR Method to call a Webpage?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2005, sqlclr

I have an asp.net mvc application that take a while to load on my production server. I would like to write a script to call my pages every 10 minutes to avoid the pages from being scrapped on the server, which would then cause the server to reload them.

I was thinking of using a SQL Server stored procedure to call my pages every 10 minutes to keep the pages alive.

I've read that I can do this using CLR, but I am not sure how. Does anyone have an example of how to call webpages in a SQL Stored Procedure using CLR?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have no idea why you would want to use a stored procedure for this.

Just write a simple console application to "call" the page. Then use a scheduled task to run the console application.

Comment: I went ahead and built a windows service application to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Code untested but something like this should work.

You'll probably also need TRUSTWORTHY SET.

```
ALTER DATABASE Foo SET TRUSTWORTHY ON;
```

Code:

```
public partial class WebProc
{
   [SqlFunction()]
   public static string WebQuery()
   {
      WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
      WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
      Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
      StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
      string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
      return responseFromServer;
   }
}
```

Comment: -1: especially inside of SQL Server, I think you'd better put response, dataStream, and reader inside of `using` blocks.

Comment: @John. Sure the code can be made safe. This was merely to illustrate the "How do I" question. As I'm not answering the "Should I question".

Comment: far too many developers copy / paste what they see on SO and elsewhere. Fix the code and I'll remove the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

> I have no idea why you would want to use a stored procedure for this.
>
> Just write a simple console application to "call" the page. Then use a scheduled task to run the console application.

You *could* do that (of course) but that's not what the question was asking ;)

Jafin's answer is correct for the question.

The *best* answer (IMHO) would be to fix your production server (i.e. reconfigure the settings) so that it doesn't "scrap" your pages every 10 minutes.

Why use a jackhammer (console app or .net inside the database or whatever) when a regular one will do?